# Testing on Web Browse and Mobile application simultaneously using cucumber

Tags: cucumber, capybara, calabash

I would like to know how to execute tests that involve a **web browser** and **Mobile application** simultaneously during a single test run.

Specifically, calabash and capybara environments.

Comment: You can get the option as a input. Example: cucumber -t @test_sceanrio platform = '<Web/mobile>'. In hooks.rb/env.rb you can set calabash environment if platform as mobile

Answer (score 0):

An old question now but in case it's useful to anyone, you can achieve this by starting your calabash tests as usual, but in your set up define a browser instance.  e.g.

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

Then calabash will work as normal and for any steps where you want to use the browser you can pass in @browser.

It's worth noting that the browser instance will be running on the machine that's driving the test run rather than on the device.